# Cannot Add Table (with primary key) to EF Designer

Tags: entity-framework

I'm unable to drag a new table onto my entity framework designer. When I drag the table over the designer, the icon of a circle with a line through it shows up and I can't drop the table onto the designer.

From my research, it seems the biggest issue is the table missing a primary key. Well, my table has a primary key.

[Another site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1661255.aspx/1) suggested: "Please remember that your tables should be related to each other instead of isolating themselves from each other." I'm not sure how that makes sense. Some tables just aren't related to others.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found it. This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/) states that if the Visual Database Tools DLL gets updated, that could cause the problem. I did indeed just recently install SQL Server Data Tools.

However, instead of trying that fix, I found a decent work-around: I simply right-clicked on the designer and chose Update Model from Database... That worked.

Hope this helps someone else that's having this issue...

[image]